# VirtualBox 4.3 Guest Additions on OSX guest

Tags: virtualbox, macosx, guest-additions

Im running virtual box 4.3 on ubuntu 13.10, everything goes fine with windows guests but for Mac osx (Mountain Lyon) I just cant find how to install Guest additions. Seems like there's no osx installer in the iso.
thanks in advance-

Comment: Since Apple only allows OS X to be legally installed on bare metal machines manufactured by Apple. There is no legitimate reason for a OS X Guest Additions. This is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: I never said Im not using a machine manufactured by Apple. Isnt legal to install ubuntu on my MacBook Pro and vbox?

Comment: I am not suggesting you are doing something illegal. I am just telling you why Oracle, the corporation responsible to VirtualBox will never produce such a guest addition. You could run Windows on Apple machine and run VirtualBox on top of Windows. I doubt you will be able to get OS X guest addition on VirtualBox running on Windows host. In the end, the issue is with Oracle and Apple, nothing to do with Ubuntu. See https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=31104

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right, VirtualBox doesn't have guest additions for OSX. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes

They only list Mac OSX Server (Leopard, Snow Leopard) under Mac and even that doesn't have guest additions.

It has something to do with licensing restrictions:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=31104

Comment: ok thanks, any workaround or something to share folders and to fix screen size?

Comment: @NicoGrunfeld An alternative (but hacky and slow) solution: You can use Google Drive or Dropbox to sync some files..