# Can I access files between a ubuntu 14.04 guest and a mac host on virtualbox guest additions?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, mac, virtualization

I suspect it cannot be done. The closest 'answer' I found was [VirtualBox 4.3 Guest Additions on OSX guest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372982/virtualbox-4-3-guest-additions-on-osx-guest) but I would like to go with Ubuntu 14.04 guest on a iMac host. I have not been successful in installing ubuntu on my mid-2011 12,1 imac  OS X 10.9.3 even after following several guides, but I can run 14.04 on that iMac. I have virtualbox 4.3.12 with the extension pack installed and Guest Additions on the Ubuntu 14.04 guest. Fading hope.

scott

Comment: You may also be interested in these Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest and http://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access files between host and guest operating systems. It is done via so called shared folder. This is folder on your host file system and it is mounted, and hence accessible, in the guest system.

You can create and set up the shared folder in the virtual machine properties - just look into it and you will easily find proper options. The tricky part is that your guest user account must belong to proper group to access shared folder mounted under guest Ubuntu - just look into /mnt to find shared folder mounting point and check the group name. After adding your account to that group and re-login, you will have full access to write and read files in shared folder.

Comment: Thank you! I was reading about shared folders hoping to find just that but it escaped me. I'll look for just how, now I know it can be done. It is my own machine and I am the only account and do have admin rights. Thank you again, the networking is not my expertise.

Comment: I have changed permission of a USB drive on the host to read for all but do not see it or how to specify it on the guest. I don't see how to mount it - it is shared and I rebooted also.

Comment: I have added/changed permissions/sharing on the host. I found the folder in /Media of the guest but when I try to view the folder it says II don't have permission.... I missed something obvious I guess...

Comment: You probably just need to add your user to the `vboxsf` group in the guest (Ubuntu) system - something like `sudo gpasswd --add username vboxsf` - and then log the user out and back in.

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you! That was exactly it! Now I have access to 500GB of music files from any music player, woweezowee! PERFECT

Comment: works now, see: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88302677/Screenshot%20from%202014-06-10%2015%3A26%3A56.png